# insert values in xml field MS SQl

Tags: xml, insert, sql-server-2012

I have a xml fiedl in MS Sql database table. The table Name "Items" I trying to figure out how to insert values into this xml field.  The name of the xml field "ItemSpecifics" criteria field ItemID, which is also in "Item" table

The nested fields I'm trying to update are; "cyclecounterror" and "salesperson" "cyclecounterror" to yes "salesperson" to Alex where "ItemID"= 26575 Here is the example of one record:

```
  <selectedvalues> 
<selectedvalue> 
    <NAME>salesperson paid</NAME> 
    <value>false</value> 
  </selectedvalue> 
  <selectedvalue> 
    <NAME>manufacturer</NAME> 
    <value /> 
  </selectedvalue> 
  <selectedvalue> 
    <NAME>resolved</NAME> 
    <value>false</value> 
  </selectedvalue> 
<selectedvalue> 
    <NAME>cyclecounterror</NAME> 
    <value>no</value> 
  </selectedvalue> 
</selectedvalues>
```

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Update fields "cyclecounterror" and "Salesperson" based on "ItemID" For exmaple:  set Cyclecounterror to yes and Salesperson to Alex where ItemID=26575. It would be simple Update query if "Salesperson" and "Cyclecounterror" were not in xml field.

Comment: There isn't an ItemID in your xml. As posted there just isn't enough information to give you an answer here.

Comment: ItemID is the separate field. Its not in xml field.

Comment: OK. What have you tried? If this is just xml there are literally thousands and thousands of examples of how to update xml in sql server.